# Detect invalid numbers in text box

Tags: c#, textbox, numeric

I am developing a Windows Form Application. One of my text box suppose to receive a numerical value for further processing. The input can be a round number or a number with a decimal point. If the user enters an invalid character other than a `number, backspace key or a dot(".")`, A label with a warning will appear. This is my code:

```
private void TextBoxMainManualCpkVal_KeyPress(System.Object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if ((!IsNumeric(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != ControlChars.Back && e.KeyChar != "."))
    {
        LabelWarnMainCpk.Visible = true;
        e.KeyChar = null;
    }
    else
    {
        LabelWarnMainCpk.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

> Valid Case:
>   [image: Valid Input]
>
> Invalid Case:
>   [image: Invalid Input where I entered 1.2"w". Letter "w" is INVALID]

Now, I wanted to make sure if the user enters a funny numeric value such as `"1.2.3"` The warning label shall show.

> Currently:
>   [image: Invalid Input That Does Not Shows the warning label]

How Do I achieve this?

Comment: Is `1.` a valid value? `.1.2`? `.`? What should happen if I **paste in** `1.2Bob`?

Comment: 1. is still valid as it is considered as 1.0, 1.2Bob cannot be entered as it will show the warning label and .1.2 is not valid and I am looking for how to detect that

Answer (score 3):

For windows forms application you can use a masked input to be sure, that user can enter only that values which you allows him to enter by mask. Like this - 5 numbers, one dot, and two more numbers after

[image]

and it will looks like this in output:

[image]

Comment: Good suggestion, but I do not want to use a maskedtextbox. Reason is not to limit the user's input in term of a decimal value

Comment: @Hari look here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask(v=vs.110).aspx you can use optional masking element (like 9 instead 0) and put in mask so many elems what you need for any user input variant

Answer (score 0):

Use Regex:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^[0-9]([.,][0-9]{1,3})?$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var match = regex.Match(inputString);
bool isValid = match != null && match.Success;
```

An alternative solution found in stackoverflow:

```
bool IsDecimalFormat(string input) {
  Decimal dummy;
  return Decimal.TryParse(input, out dummy);
}
```